# socket connect to invalid ip don't raise error (python)

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm Trying to send and receive data using TCP communication.

I tried to communicate using the IP of a specific embedded device, but i check that the 'connect' was going well even when the device was turned off.

When the device is turned off, I want to output an error message, but I can't check it because the connect is performed normally.

So, I checked with wireshark and I found something strange.

My code

```
import socket

HOST = '105.0.0.121' # random IP
PORT = 9999       
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client_socket.settimeout(2)
client_socket.connect((HOST, PORT))

client_socket.send('some data'.encode())

data = client_socket.recv(1024)
print('Received', repr(data.decode()))

client_socket.close()
```

I use random IP 105.0.0.121

I expect at client_socket.connect((HOST, PORT)) raise an error, but at line 'data = client_socket.recv(1024)' raise the error that print "socket.timeout: timed out".

[wireshark image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QPSE.png)

When I checked with Wireshark, it seems to have sent an **"ACK"** from 105.0.121.

Because of receiving ACK, it seems that the "connect" has passed normally, but I don't know why this phenomenon occurs.

Give me a help plz
Thank you

Comment: Can you paste your error message？

Comment: I asked because there was no error on the "connect" function.

Comment: Please show your full traceback message.